# Laravel Nova doesn't find some Models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

With some Models, when I make a new Nova Resource for them, seems that Nova can't find the Model because they doesn't show on sidebar (i can't reach them also by URL, giving me a 404).
But this happens only for specific Models and if I try to modify the target Model in the Resource with another one (editing the $model variable), it works and shows the Resource in the sidebar (but with the wrong model). Nova isn't throwing me any error so the debugging is getting crazy difficult.

The Models that doesn't work in my project are named "Product" and "Company".

I'm using Laravel 7.28.3, Nova 3.9.1, MariaDB 10.4.11 and PHP 7.4.1 with Homestead.

Here's the code of Product resource:

```
<?php

namespace App\Nova;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\ID;
use Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest;

class Product extends Resource
{
    /**
     * The model the resource corresponds to.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $model = \App\Product::class;

    /**
     * The single value that should be used to represent the resource when being displayed.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $title = 'title';

    /**
     * The columns that should be searched.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $search = [
        'id', 'name'
    ];

    /**
     * Get the fields displayed by the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the cards available for the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function cards(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the filters available for the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function filters(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the lenses available for the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function lenses(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the actions available for the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function actions(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

And here's the Model code:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;

class Product extends Model implements HasMedia
{
    use InteractsWithMedia;

    public function visits()
    {
        return visits($this);
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function company() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
    }

    public function productVariety() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ProductVariety', 'product_variety_id');
    }

    public function productSpecies() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ProductSpecies', 'product_species_id');
    }

    public function productNutrients() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductNutrient');
    }

    public function baseProduct() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Product', 'base_product_id');
    }

    public function recipes() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Recipe', 'base_product_id');
    }

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'company_id', 'imageline_id', 'products_species_id', 'products_varieties_id', 'base_product_id',
        'name', 'scientific_name', 'production_start', 'production_end', 'production_city', 'description', 'story', 'curiosities', 'advices', 'quantity_advices', 'why_good', 'who_good',
        'is_base_product', 'show_related_recipes', 'show_related_products'
    ];

}
```

Comment: `composer dumpautoload`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `AuthServiceProvider` on `app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php` if there is a **Policy** set to this model. Then on your policy class (probably `ProductPolicy` which is bind to `Product` model, check `view` and `viewAny` methods, these methods must return `true` or conditional `true`.

Comment: I didn't know that Nova automatically applies existing Policies. The methods view() and viewAny() doesn't had a return so this prevented Nova to showing the models.